# How to keep focus Style (added class) until you click out (onBlur) in a component

Tags: reactjs

Im refactoring and improving a component into React ES6. Basically is a search box imput into a div with styles. the main fuction is when you click the div itself add a class to change style and idicate that you are focusing it. The classnames toggle works fine but i have to do something different, i have to keep the style of the focus until you click out even you click again on the imput. The problem is that if i do another click on the search box itself it toggles the class. How i can keep the focused class until user do onBlur?

```
import React from "react";

class StatusBarSearchBox extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {focused: false}
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({ focused: !this.state.focused });
    }

    render() {
        var cx = require('classnames');
        var focusedConainer = cx ({
            'statusbar-searchbox-container' : true,
            'focus' : this.state.focused
        });
        var focusedIcon = cx ({
            'statusbar-searchbox-icon' : true,
            'focus' : this.state.focused
        });
        var actionButton = cx ({
            'statusbar-searchbox-action-button' : true,
            'focus' : this.state.focused
        });          

        return (
            <div className={focusedConainer} onClick={this.handleClick} onBlur={this.handleClick} >
                <div className={focusedIcon}></div>
                <input className="statusbar-searchbox-input" type="text" placeholder="BUSCAR..." />
                <div className={actionButton}></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

module.exports = StatusBarSearchBox;
```

onBlur works fine except when you do 2 clicks on the search box and then you click ouside because it toggles the style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got this component, it works fine, but the next improvement is to do autofocus on the input even clicking outside but into the container div of the search box. Is that possible??

Here is the code:

```
import React from "react";

class StatusBarSearchBoxView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {focused: false}
        this.toggleSearchBox = this.toggleSearchBox.bind(this)
        this.clickOut = this.clickOut.bind(this)
    }

    toggleSearchBox() {
        if (this.state = {focused: false}) {
            this.setState({ focused: !this.state.focused });
        } else {
            this.setState({ focused: this.state.focused });
        }
    }

    clickOut() {
        this.setState({ focused: !this.state.focused });
    }

    render() {
        var cx = require('classnames');
        var focusedConainer = cx ({
            'statusbar-searchbox-container' : true,
            'focus' : this.state.focused
        });
        var focusedIcon = cx ({
            'statusbar-searchbox-icon' : true,
            'focus' : this.state.focused
        });
        var actionButton = cx ({
            'statusbar-searchbox-action-button' : true,
            'focus' : this.state.focused
        });          

        return (
            <div className={focusedConainer} onClick={this.toggleSearchBox} onBlur={this.clickOut} >
                <div className={focusedIcon}></div>
                <input className="statusbar-searchbox-input" type="text" placeholder="BUSCAR..." />
                <div className={actionButton}></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

module.exports = StatusBarSearchBoxView;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the event handler conditionally.

```
<div
  className={focusedConainer}
  onClick={!this.state.focused && this.handleClick}
  onBlur={this.state.focused && this.handleClick}
>
```

You should also probably rename the `handleClick` method to something like `toggleFocus`.

Comment: Hi, i tried it, it works but not as i want, im not sure it that is the best or compact method to build this kind of "toggles", if you see my later answer with that boolean i can do fine the keeping style even i click as much as i want on the focused element, the problem is because the onBlur is not working and i thinking about it.